# How to fix PHP Warning: Undefined array key in Code for WooCommerce category image switch on hover

Tags: php, arrays, key, undefined

I have this code in my child theme functions.php file:

```
// add hover image to woo category page
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'mem_add_on_hover_shop_loop_image' ) ; 
        function mem_add_on_hover_shop_loop_image() {
        $image_id = wc_get_product()->get_gallery_image_ids()[0] ; 
        if ( $image_id ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image_id, 'woocommerce_thumbnail' ) ; 
        } else { 
            //echo wp_get_attachment_image( wc_get_product()->get_image_id() ) ; 
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( wc_get_product()->get_image_id(), 'woocommerce_thumbnail' ) ; 
        }
    }
```

It works and it switches the category image on hover.

The problem is that a PHP error is showing related to this line:
$image_id = wc_get_product()->get_gallery_image_ids()[0] ;

The error is PHP Warning: Undefined array key 0

How can I fix this please?

Thank you
Tamsin

I have not tried a fix yet.

Comment: You check that `get_gallery_image_ids()` returns an array first before trying to consume array index `0`

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how I can do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if `get_gallery_image_ids` returns an array. If it does then check key 0 (first element) exists. If it does then you're free to use it.

```php
...

// Get all IDs
$idList = wc_get_product()->get_gallery_image_ids(); 

// Check if the IDs are an array and key 0 (first element) exists
if (is_array($idList) && array_key_exists(0, $idList)) {
    // Get the first element
    $image_id = $idList[0];

    echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, 'woocommerce_thumbnail' ) ; 
} else { 
    echo wp_get_attachment_image(wc_get_product()->get_image_id(), 'woocommerce_thumbnail' ) ; 
}
```

Edit,

> Should I add it to the functions file

You should edit your `mem_add_on_hover_shop_loop_image` function with this code. Final code should look like this,

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'mem_add_on_hover_shop_loop_image');
function mem_add_on_hover_shop_loop_image()
{
    // Get all IDs
    $idList = wc_get_product()->get_gallery_image_ids();

    // Check if the IDs are an array and key 0 (first element) exists
    if (is_array($idList) && array_key_exists(0, $idList)) {
        // Get the first element
        $image_id = $idList[0];

        echo wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, 'woocommerce_thumbnail');
    } else {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image(wc_get_product()->get_image_id(), 'woocommerce_thumbnail');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry not to understand what to do with this code. Should I add it to the functions file?

Comment: I did try and it wouldn't save and showed this:

Comment: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 360 of file wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_gallery_image_ids() on bool in wp-content/themes/astra-child/functions.php:360
Stack trace:
#0 wp-settings.php(585): include()
#1 wp-config.php(82): require_once('/www/xxxxxxxx...')
#2 wp-load.php(50): require_once('/www/xxxxxxxx...')
#3 wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/www/xxxxxx..')
#4 wp-admin/theme-editor.php(10): require_once('/www/xxxxxxx...')
#5 {main}
  thrown

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. That code seems to work and I assume the Undefined key error is resolved now. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @water please close all newly asked questions seeking advice on how to check if an array key exists.  This topic is well covered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Will do next time.